# eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n$ order real matrix , $\lambda $ be a real number and $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\vec{v}\neq 0$. Suppose that $(A-\lambda I)^k\vec{v} =0$ for some positive integer $k$. Then 
how to prove the statement given below is always true?

$\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$.
I know this statement will be true when $\vec{v}$ is eigenvector. But I don't know how this will be true for any non-zero $\vec{v}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k=1$, then according to the assumption, we have $(A-\lambda I) v = 0$. But this is equivalent to $Av = \lambda v$. So in this case, apparently $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Suppose that $k\ne 1$. Then we have $(A-\lambda I)^k v = (A-\lambda I)(A-\lambda I)^{k-1} v = 0$. But $(A - \lambda I)^{k-1} v $ is just another vector. Denote it as $w$. Then we have $(A - \lambda I) w = 0$.